# Split shapefile features and transpose attributes

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

QGIS v3.4

I have a single shapefile layer with overlapping features. I wish to intersect the features against themselves and transpose the summary of attributes in the output. The image below will help explain the goal.

What sequence of processing tools should I use to do this? The output should leave me without any overlapping features.

[image]

Comment: You can try to use SAGA: Polygon self-intersection Algorithm under processing tools

Comment: @eurojam That's perfect, do you want to post this as an answer?

Comment: @James B: it's not like you described in your image: for each intersection you will not get one new column...for that reason it was only an idea commited as a comment

Comment: @eurojam You're right, for the most part this has worked by adding new 'ID' field separating each unique value by a pipe. There are some duplicate geometries. The duplicates do not summarise all the values in a single feature but randomly combine them across each overlapping feature. Proceeding this...I have tried the 'point on surface' algorithm followed by the 'join attributes by location (summary)' algorithm on a cleaned version (no duplicates) of the polygon shapefile. The result retains the longest chain of characters in any one of the duplicate geometries/points. Not a solution...

Comment: Are u ok with aggregating area types **in a single column** and a given separator character ?

Comment: @snaileater absolutley

Comment: Are u able to have **individual ids** for each of your polygon of the start layer ?

Comment: @snaileater Yes, I can use expression '@row_num' to create ids

Comment: I have found this very similar question (if not the same) and currently using Kazuhito's expression which is ticking away. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256731/how-to-get-all-attributes-from-overlapping-polygons-with-identical-geometry-into

Comment: As it was pointed out by @eurojam, you can use "SAGA:Polygon self-intersection Algorithm under processing tools"; but in a PyQGIS script for including only required parameter options and to get desired layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was pointed out by @eurojam, you can use "SAGA:Polygon self-intersection Algorithm under processing tools"; but in a PyQGIS script for including only required parameter options and to get desired layer.

For testing above approach, I created a single shapefile layer with overlapping features, similar to your shapefile, where it is not showing intersections by using transparency options:

[image]

PyQGIS script ran at Pyton Console of QGIS 3.4 it is as follow:

```
import processing

polys = QgsVectorLayer("/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/overlapped_features.shp","self_intersections","ogr")
output = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/intersection.shp"
processing.runAndLoadResults("saga:polygonselfintersection", 
                {'POLYGONS':polys, 
                 'INTERSECT':output})
```

After running it, resulting layer can be observed at below image:

[image]

It can be also observed that it was create a new field where it is recorded all nine single features or self intersections.